# Сделать активным инпут, если соответствующий radio активен

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<input id="a" type="radio" hidden/>
{!! Form::number('aa', null, ['id'=>'aA', 'disabled'=>true]) !!}
{!! Form::number('bb', null, ['id'=>'bB', 'disabled'=>true]) !!}
<input id="c" type="radio" hidden/>
{!! Form::number('dd', null, ['id'=>'dD', 'disabled'=>true]) !!}
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `radio` "a" были активными инпуты "aa","bb"?
А при нажатии на `radio` "c" были активными инпуты "dd"?

```
<script>
    $('input[id="a"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'checked') {
            $('[id="aA"]').removeProp("disabled");
            $('[id="bB"]').removeProp("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $('[id="aA"]').prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $('[id="bB"]').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Не помогло..
upd. вижу `if(здесь ошибку)`, как проверять, "активен" ли `radio`? `:onchecked`?

Comment: А что у вас за атрибут такой `hidden`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если разбить `disabled` `input`-ы на группы (например, с помощью классов) и привязать каждый radio button к конкретной группе (например, с помощью data-атрибута), то можно сделать так:

```js
$(function() {
  $(":radio").on("click", function() {
    var dataClass = $(this).data("class");
    $(".js-all").each(function() {
        this.disabled = !$(this).hasClass(dataClass);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="a" type="radio" name="myname" data-class="js-a" />a<br/>
<input class="js-all js-a" disabled/><br/>
<input class="js-all js-a" disabled/><br/>
<input id="c" type="radio" name="myname" data-class="js-c"/>c<br/>
<input class="js-all js-c" disabled/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Учитывая что клик по radio button уже говорит о том, что он выбран, остаётся только активировать нужные `input` и заблокировать остальные.

Radio button-ы имеют одинаковое `name`, дабы выбор одного из них приводил к снятию выбора с других.

Comment: спасибо, то, что нужно! можно ли таким образом расширить функцию, чтобы прятать-показывать `div`-блоки? https://jsfiddle.net/ua3hrhd1/ вот моя попытка, но теперь активный `radio` прячет все, что к нему не относится

Comment: @Tarasovych на здоровье. Так как `disabled` надо делать для одних элементов, а `hidden` - для других, то имеет смысл разнести их в разные группы. Например, сделать [как-то так](https://jsfiddle.net/ua3hrhd1/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Можете проверять вот так внутри события по клику:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

Вместо:

```
if ($(this).val() === 'checked')
```

Comment: для этого нужно повесить на `radio`-инпут `unchecked`?

Comment: нет, он по умолчанию же не отмечен

Comment: сейчас `disabled` исчезает, если активен `radio`, но если `radio` не активен, `disabled` не возвращается https://jsfiddle.net/ysx0ysqe/5/

Comment: @Tarasovych потому что у вас элемент только 1 и с него не снять checked, это же не checkbox, или меняйте на checkbox но тогда не много придется переписать js, или на `id="c"` тоже надо писать js.